# How to whitelist only Google users in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How can I whitelist Google users in Firebase? I only want maybe 3 people to access my main dashboard after login. Do I have to write some rules in my db or? The code below lets me login users with Google accounts:

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(result => {
            const username = result.user.displayName;
            const userId = result.user.uid;
            navigate('/todos');
            addUser(username, userId);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This document on [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions) says you can write a function in the backend thats called `beforeCreate`. Inside this function you can verify if a user can sign up. But you first need to upgrade to an [Identity Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform)